# Determining time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm working on a problem where A is being decremented by the value of k in every iteration. K is also doubled in every iteration. So for example:

A = 30 -> 29 --> 27 --> 23 --> 15 --> 0
delta = 1 --> 2 --> 4 --> 8 --> 16

How can I assess the time complexity of this algorithm? I figure there has to be related to O(logN) due to the doubling of delta, but not sure how to intuitively/mathematically arrive at a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The total size of N decrements is 2^N - 1 (prove this by induction), so from A, it takes ceil(log2(A + 1)) decrements to reach 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is in between `2^n` and `2^(n-1)`, i.e., `2^(n-1) <= A < 2^n`, it will take exactly `n` steps to get to a `non-positive` value, since in `n` steps the total decrement is`1+2+..+2^(n-1)=2^n-1` (use induction on `n` to prove). Hence, time complexity `= n = lg 2^n = 1 + lg 2^(n-1) <= 1 + lg(A)`, where `lg` is `log` `base 2`.